# Extracting words From a comma separated string without using an array

Tags: c#, string

Are there any in built libraries in c# to Extract words From a comma separated string without using an array.
ya i know of split function but if i'm right we need to use an array for it...
i dont want to use an array...

Comment: How do you want to store them?

Comment: and then passing on to some other function.....

Comment: In order to store multiple values into one variable, you need an array so I don't know what you mean with "without using an array".

Comment: @neil i dont want to store them that y i dont want an array .....just want to compare it some value...

Comment: @Jay: You would need to store individual words in some kind of list, be it array or not. There is no other way you would be able to pass a collection of items without using Array or some other variants, such as Collections.

Comment: @TimS. i just want to fetch one value at a time and compare them with some value....

Comment: Then would't @Dennis' solution get you part way there?  Within the foreach you could do your comparison.

Comment: @Jay: If you just want to compare them, you would at least need a temporary array. If implemented properly, the memory occupied by array would be released as soon as it gets out of scope.

Comment: @Jay: You will need an array/list in order to iterate through the results.

Comment: @Jay get a single value at a time is very inefficient. Looping through an array is much more efficient to be honest.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to use the Contains method to check if a word exists in a given string.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment on your own post, I assume this is what you want:

```
String myString = "this,is,a,string";
String separator = ",";
MethodName(myString.Split(separator.ToCharArray()));

...
public void MethodName(String[] words) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

If not, clarify your question.

---

**EDIT**

Please, PLEASE just be more clear with your question. What do you wish to check? If a word matches a certain pattern? If the word exists at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a very nasty `for` loop where you search for the `,` values and then compare from the start of 1 `,` to the next.  You could use `SubString()` and `IndexOf()` to achieve this, but this isn't very performant nor elegant.

Comment: ya that is some thing that i want .....but can u suggest a more optimized way of doing it

Comment: In all honesty, I would say that the array is the optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying from a different angle.

You could loop through your words to compare and check if they exist in a given string e.g.

```
string listOfWords = "Some, text, to, look, through";

if (WordExists(listOfWords, "look"))
{

}

private bool WordExists(string listToCheck, string wordToFind)
{
   return listToCheck.Contains(wordToFind);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `String.Split()` method

```
var myString = "Hello, World, I, am, a, comma, separated, string"
foreach (var item in myString.Split(new Char [] {',')) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Also, the Split method doesn't accept a string, but a char array.

Comment: @NeilKnight I don't think that OP cares about the language internals in this case. I assume he just doesn't want to have to explicitly store the strings in an array. But maybe I'm wrong, thanks for the downvote anyway.